TIA with reverse bias adapted
I have adapted my circuit of the last post TIA circuit with reverse biases photodiode, thanks for the feedback, but it still doesn't work. I have removed the voltage divider for the positive input voltage and to get the right dc bias, I remove the dc part and add it again. The circuit gives now a 0.5V output voltage before the ac coupling capacitor, but not the 10kHz sine wave I modulate the light with on a 6V dc bias?


I'm unclear on your simulation.  Is Ipd supposed to be the dark current?  If so, what's the value?  I'd also imagine you would want to add a decoupling cap across R7 to reduce noise, but that's not your issue.

What's Vout if you disconnect the photodiode?

Note that LF357 output voltage of +0.5V is outside its linear range - I'm guessing it is trying to drive down toward 0V, but is unable. Either LF357 is fried, or else dark current of the photodiode is excessive. Can you try running the photodiode with no DC bias?...that might help if dark current is the problem.

Ipd is the current the photodiode makes due to the modulated light

@Visje999 So your model does not include dark current?  Your Ipd is perfectly symmetrical around 0 A?

Your photodiode conducts enough on average to force the op amp output into saturation.  Additional small perturbations will have little effect.  You might want to consider adding a resistor to ground to bias the photodiode, and then capacitively couple the photodiode output to the positive op-amp input, so the op amp can set its own DC bias without competition.  You'll then have a 6V output with your modulation imposed on it (assuming the PD has enough bandwidth for  10KHz).

Using no reverse bias works, so I will just use that. It will give less noise, but less speed. The speed is not an issue anymore, since the ADC has limited speed anyway.

I will just use a TIA without reverse bias. The signal bandwidth is lower due to the larger capacitance, but there is less noise. Since the ADC used has limited speed, the 300kHz bandwidth looks fine. If I find the problem with the reverse bias TIA, I will post.

